# Socket.io in React Native WebView does not work at all

Tags: react-native, webview

I am building a RN app that wraps my React web app. There, I have a chat page that uses socket.io

It works perfectly fine when accessed through web browser, but it doesn't even connect to socket when accessed through RN WebView.

Please share your experience to get through this.

[React Native Webview Github issues have this issue on it](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1885)

Comment: could you solve it? similar issue here

Comment: @instantlink no I ended up creating a native page for that specific chat page.

Comment: @instantlink is not solved for now ?